# How to merge rows with the same date in google docs using arrayfunction

Tags: date, merge, google-sheets

I've looked everywhere to try to find a solution to my problem but can't find anything that will apply to my desired effect.

Data is automatically being entered into a google docs sheet that can output multiple entries for one day. I have a separate date column that I would like to use either a script or function to automatically find duplicate dates in the column and merge the data of the duplicates respective rows into a single row on another sheet containing all the entries with the combined rows. If someone could help, it would be greatly appreciated. I have provided a sample doc so you can see the data types, layout, etc.

Edit: Also I suppose it does not have to be an arrayfunction but it would have to be able to actively check new cells that are being created without input from the user.

Comment: In what way do you want the rows with equivalent dates merged, seeing they all have different data? Do you want concatenation like this: `9.04%, 55.24%`?

Comment: @Calvin No I would like the data to just be combined. Ex. 64.28% per your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is use a *Pivot Table*.

### Pivot Table

Put your Date column in the Pivot Table under Rows. This groups your data by date. Put the rest of the columns under Values. Set these to SUM.

### Parse Time

When you get to this point, you will notice all your times show zero in the pivot table. This is because they are formatted as text. To sum them, they must be formatted as time. You can parse them using this ugly formula:

```
=iferror(TIMEVALUE(iferror(left('Initial Data'!B2,search("h",'Initial Data'!B2)-1),"0")&":"&trim(left(RIGHT('Initial Data'!B2,iferror(FIND(" ",'Initial Data'!B2),len('Initial Data'!B2))),len(RIGHT('Initial Data'!B2,iferror(FIND(" ",'Initial Data'!B2),len('Initial Data'!B2))))-1))),"")
```

### Result

The final pivot table should look like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11WyCeWSWCiauQ3_NALXQjYzJ6Qu8og0IIhUTvyqPjc8/edit?usp=sharing#gid=992827072), as per your example:
[image]
You may have an extra row if your pivot table range includes blank rows. The Pivot Table will automatically update when any rows in it's reference range are added or changed.